# What issue stops .Net application to connect to SQL Server database on Windows Server 2012 when it works fine on Windows Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, odbc, windows-server-2012-r2, .net-framework-version

I am using 'odbc connection' in '.Net' application to connect to SQL Server 2012. When I execute the application on Windows Server 2008, it works fine, but when I deployed it on Windows Server 2012 R2, it does not connect. Nothing works, I changed the odbc to `SqlConnection` also. Also used ipAddress directly.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: what error are you getting ? provide details.

Comment: The error is : connection to the sql server fails, that is the log i put there and shows nothing else. Also, i developed application in 32bit os but server 2012 is 64bit, but the application is in program files(x86) folder, does that have any affect. .Net framework version 4.5.51 in 2012 and 4.5.50 in 2008

Comment: Did you created 32 bit ODBC connection from C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe ?

Comment: yes! i tested with both 64bit and 32bit for userDSN as well as systemDSN.I dont understand in windows 2008 it works but here it doesnt. Even the .Net environment seems fine. I have another c++ application on the same server that connects as well as works fine.

Comment: Check machine.config file on the server. It may have additional DbProviderFactories node. Remove additional  <DbProviderFactories /> node from it if it exists.

Comment: i checked the file, there is only mysql configuration . is it important to change that??